# Intuition about an orthogonal projection operator for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, intuition, projection-matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be of rank $r$, and $A = U\Sigma V^T$ be its SVD with $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$. Let $P_U = UU^T$ and $P_V = VV^T$ be orthogonal projectors onto the ranges of $U$ and $V$ respectively. The operator

$$\mathcal{P}_T(Z) = P_U Z + Z P_V - P_U Z P_V$$

acting on $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is an orthogonal projector onto a subspace $T$, which is a linear space spanned by elements of the form $u_k y^T$ and $x v_k^T$ for $k = 1, \dots, r$.

Can anyone provide some further intuition about $T$? How should one think about it?

Comment: Since $U$ and $V$ in the real SVD are orthogonal, $UU^T$ and $VV^T$ are both the identity. While technically the identity is an orthogonal projector, I'm pretty sure it's not what you had in mind.

Comment: @celtschk Sorry, I should have clarified: We assume a reduced SVD where $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$, $U\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$ and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, so $UU^T$ and $VV^T$ are not necessarily the identity.

Comment: Ah, I see. But "projectors onto $U$ and $V$" doesn't make sense. Rather, they are the projectors onto the image and the orthogonal space of the kernel.

Comment: Right. I did abuse notation there, I've corrected it!

Comment: Since $\mathcal P_T$ maps between two different spaces, it cannot be a projector, since the defining equation $P^2=P$ is not even defined for $P=\mathcal P_T$.

Comment: @celtschk It is a projector operator, and it does fulfil the definition of projector: $\mathcal{P}_T^2(Z) = \mathcal{P}_T (\mathcal{P}_T(Z) ) = \mathcal{P}_T(Z)$.

Comment: As far as I can see, $\mathcal P_T$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. How am I supposed to square that?

Comment: You are not supposed to square $\mathcal{P}_T$, but to compose it. For an operator, $\mathcal{P}_T^2(\cdot):= \mathcal{P}_T(\mathcal{P}_T(\cdot))$. When a projector $P$ is a mapping $P: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, then indeed $P^2(\cdot) = P(P(\cdot)) = (P*P)(\cdot)$. This is not the case here.

Comment: Ah, now I understand: $\mathcal P_T$ is *acting on* $Z\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. I understood your text as $\mathcal P_T$ being *parametrized* by $Z$. I'll edit your post to make that more clear.

Comment: BTW, looking at your user page, I notice that you didn't accept any answer to any question you asked. Did you consider none of the answers people gave to your questions helpful?

Comment: @celtschk That's right, I did not. I also didn't accept your answer because I didn't consider it very helpful. However, I appreciate your help, so I have upvoted it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I'm sorry that my answer isn't very helpful to you. Maybe if you explain *why* it is not helpful to you, I may be able to make it more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A better understanding of $\mathcal P_T$ can be achieved by looking at a special case: Namely when $P_U$ and $P_V$ are diagonal, with all the $1$ entries coming first. For example, consider $m=3$, $n=4$, $r=2$, and
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}\\
3 & 4 & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}\\
\color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}
\end{pmatrix}$$
From this, one easily can calculate that
$$P_U =
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}\\
  \color{grey}{0} & 1 & \color{grey}{0}\\
  \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
P_V =
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}\\
  \color{grey}{0} & 1 & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}\\
  \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}\\
  \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then for a general $3\times 4$ matrix
$$Z = \begin{pmatrix}
z_{11} & z_{12} & z_{13} & z_{14}\\
z_{21} & z_{22} & z_{23} & z_{24}\\
z_{31} & z_{32} & z_{33} & z_{34}
\end{pmatrix}$$
you get
$$\mathcal P_T(Z)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{z_{11}} & \color{red}{z_{12}} & z_{13} & z_{14}\\
\color{red}{z_{21}} & \color{red}{z_{22}} & z_{23} & z_{24}\\
z_{31} & z_{32} & \color{grey}{0} & \color{grey}{0}
\end{pmatrix}$$
So you can see that for $v\in\ker(A)$, $\mathcal P_T(Z)v$ = $P_UZv$, that is, after applying $Z$, they are projected to the range of $A$. However, for vectors orthogonal to the kernel, the image under $P_T(Z)$ is just the image under $Z$. That is, $\mathcal P_T$ removes that part of $Z$ that maps the kernel of $A$ to the space orthogonal to the range of $A$.